# Multiple CosmosClient for single cosmos db account

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I read online that one should keep single instance of CosmosClient for a cosmos db account per application.

In my case, my app & cosmos db is deployed to multiple regions.
Normally the app will read from the cosmos db in the same region.

However, in some scenario I want my app (whichever region it is running) to read from single cosmos db region, e.g. East US always.

Reason is, our cosmos db is on bounded staleness consistency, so data might not be replicated to other read regions instantaneously.

If I always write & read from the same region, I will be guaranteed to see the document there. So I am sacrificing latency for consistency in that scenario.

In order to achieve this, I have to specify which region I want to read from

```
var clientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
                {
                    ApplicationRegion = "East US"
                };
                return new CosmosClient(_cosmosDbDataConnectionOptions.CosmosDbUrl, new DefaultAzureCredential(), clientOptions);
```

I want to use this CosmosClient for specific scenario.

In normal case, I will set
`ApplicationRegion = <app deployed region>`

This requires me to have 2 CosmosClient for the same cosmos db account.  Does it make sense to have 2 CosmosClient then ? Or is there any other recommended approach to this problem.

I looked up google and found out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3?tabs=trace-net-core#sdk-usage . This recommends me to have 1 cosmos client per app. But in my case, I have to set read region differently per scenario.

Comment: Still I don't understand why would you need 2 clients? You can read the region from Appsetting or environment variable and replace right?

Comment: @Sajeetharan - The region can be stored in app settings but your client instance is kind of tied to the region. Unless we have the capability to specify region when we are executing commands using a `CosmosClient` instance, we need to have separate instances for each region I think.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more "Reason is, our cosmos db is on bounded staleness consistency, so data might not be replicated to other read regions instantaneously."? How would you detect this scenario programmatically to choose another client that is targeting your main region?

Comment: So to give example. Let's say my service is running in West US and East US. My cosmos db is also deployed to West US[Read] and East US[Write,Read]
By this setting, all cosmos writes go to East US. For read, West US service will read from West US and East US will read from East US. Simple so far. (@Sajeetharan yes I am reading region from Appsetting. Each region has its own client)

But in this approach, when West US service writes to --> East US cosmos db and then immediately tries to read from West US cosmos db, it might not find the document replicated there yet.

Comment: So sometimes, I want to let West US service READ from East US. In this case, it will always find the document there, because it is reading from the Write region.

Comment: Caveat is, I only want my West US to read from East US in certain scenarios. In normal scenarios, I want my West US to read from West US. Hence, within my West US service, I need 2 `CosmosClient`s , one that reads from West US and one that reads from East US. @MatiasQuaranta I am not detecting whether data has been replicated or not. I have multiple scenarios that hits this cosmos code path, let's say to check transaction history and to get some cache. I don't need strong consistency for cache, but I do need for transaction history. So for transaction history I want to read from East US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the concern is about Consistency, then the SessionToken might help (Session Token from the Write on a Read call even if they are different client instances). If you have other scenarios where the logic is different and you, for whatever reason, want to change the read endpoint, yes, there is no way to flip it on a running client or say for a particular request, that you want it to go to another reagion.